# pandas to_latex() escaping "\\newline" for use in LaTex

Tags: pandas, escaping, latex

I am struggling with inexplicable behavior differences between Windows and Mac handling of \newline in a jinja template string.

I have a string, `mystring = '123 \\newline 456'`, that is inside a dataframe.  When I use pandas to_latex() on a Mac, this gets converted to `123 \textbackslashnewline`.  But on Windows, it gets converted to `123 \textbackslash newline`

The difference between the two complicates the work-around, which is to replace `\textbackslash` with an empty string.  On the Windows version I need to include the space and on the Mac version I need to not include the space.

Is there a better way to incorporate `\newline` into the table?  I tried `r'\newline'` and I tried just `'\newline'` and neither work.  The reason the latter doesn't work is that the IDE I am using (PyCharm) interprets the single slash as a line break rather than as part of the string.  The double-slash that I use is simply meant to get around that, but then to_latex() interprets the double slash as `\textblackslash`.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the issue was really with pandas to_latex() command and have edited the original question.

For the Windows version, pandas was replacing `\\newline` with '\textbackslash newline'.  But on the Mac, it was replacing it with '\textbackslashnewline' without the space.  I was then using:

```
.replace('textbackslash', '')
```

which worked on the Mac but failed on Windows because of the extra space.  What I cannot figure out though is why there is a difference between the Mac and Windows to_latex() functions.

Note that I am aware of the `escape=False` option in to_latex(), however that messes up instances where I want the parts of the string escaped (e.g. `\$`).